# What are the default WPF ListView keyboard shortcuts

Tags: wpf, listview

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all default keyboard (and perhaps mouse) shortcuts supported by WPF ListView? I have a requirement to document all shortcuts supported by my application. The application contains a number of ListView-s and I need to document shortcuts for those as well. From experience I know some of them such as Select All (Ctrl-A), Select Item (Ctrl-Space), navigate Up and Down with arrows, and some mouse based such as shift-click and control-click. But what other shortcuts and mouse actions are supported by the control?
Thanks in advance,
Leo